# Deploying through SFDX source command with -x parameter

Tags: salesforcedx

I have a pipeline that deploys through a command:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -x manifest/package.xml -u Prod -l RunLocalTests
```

But my issue is even when I use a package.xml with two fields for Case,it deploys the entire case object?
Is it a Normal behaviour? Is there a way I can only deploy the things I want to, instead of everything?
My package.xml which deploys entire Case object:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Case.R2_CAS_PKL_Reason_cancelled_case__c</members>
        <members>Case.R1_CAS_PKL_SubtypeCE__c</members>
        <members>Case.R1_CAS_PKL_TypeCE__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Case.CCPO_profile_no_editable</members>
        <name>ValidationRule</name>
    </types>
    <version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: What happens if you do this via mdapi deploy or from workbench ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a limitation of the package.xml format; it has to convert to mdapi format, which requires a full object. Instead, you can use the -p option:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default/objects/Case/fields/R2_CAS_PKL_Reason_cancelled_case__c,force-app/main/default/objects/Case/fields/R1_CAS_PKL_SubtypeCE__c,force-app/main/default/objects/Case/fields/R1_CAS_PKL_TypeCE__c,force-app/main/default/objects/Case/validationRules/CCPO_profile_no_editable
```

Alternatively, if you have just the metadata you want to deploy in its own package, you could use that as well.

Comment: Thanks @SFDCfox but it is one-off basis solution.The package keeps changing every time.I have a Jenkins pipeline which kicks off after a merge request.Yes I can do it for this instance but then i have to manually sync it my version control so that future deployment which happens through a branch, should not overwrite the today's deployed changes..No?

Comment: @Chetan There are other potential solutions, but it sounds like this isn't one of them (necessarily). There's some [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ci_jenkins.htm) you should read.

Answer (score 0):

This particular behavior is logged as issue on SFDC CLI Github : https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/156

I ran into the same issue and I have a bash script to delete the files I don't want to deploy from `force-app` folder but keep only the files that I want to deploy.